# Baffled: Django "could not import app.views" but can import app, in WSGI?

Tags: python, django, django-views, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm having an odd Django problem, running Django with mod_wsgi.

Django is finding `urls.py`, and then saying:

```
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import app.views. Error was: No module named views
```

Bizarrely, if I have

```
import app
```

in the import statements in `urls.py` I don't get an error (until it hits `app.views` as above), but if I have

```
from app import views
```

in my import statements, I get an error.

My python path, as shown in the Django debug info, has both the containing folder and the app folder on it. If I run Python from the command line, I can import `app.views` just fine. I can run the app using `python manage.py runserver` just fine.

I've tried printing the python path to stderr from `urls.py` too, and it has the path to app in it.

What could be going on?

My first thought was that there might not be an `__init__.py` in the app folder, but there is.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In the runserver app, if I try

```
print app.__file__
>> \path\to\app\__init__.py
```

But in the wsgi version, I only see:

```
print app.__file__
>> \path\to\app\
```

In other words, it's just not finding `__init__.pyc`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a circular dependency - something in `views` is importing another module, which itself is trying to import `views`.

Comment: I've replaced the contents of `views.py` with `print 'hello'`, but still the same error. Argh!

Comment: Also, I can run the Django app just fine using `python manage.py runserver`. The problem only exists with WSGI.

Comment: If the circular import cannot be found then you can try WSGI script described at end of 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html' as workaround.

Comment: @Graham thanks - I'll try your script. Sounds like it's not an uncommon problem.

Comment: I've since found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749033/problem-with-django-using-apache2-mod-wsgi-occassionally-is-unable-to-import which sounds like precisely the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Your web server is out of file handles. Reconfigure the WSGI app for daemon mode.

Comment: thanks - any pointers for how to do this? (google is not being my friend today) - I'm trying WSGIDaemonProcess as defined here http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango but not succeeding.

Comment: also, I get the error even immediately after I've restarted apache - would it have run out of file handles at that point?

Comment: Running out of file handles would be a different error. Is more likely a circular import or import ordering problem as Daniel noted.